# Calculating a basis given some constraints.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

> Have a vector space formed by the vectors $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)$ that
>   satisfy
>
> $$\begin{cases} x_1+x_2-x_3-3x_4=0\\ 2x_1+x_3-2x_4=0 \end{cases}$$
>
> Find a basis and also the dimension of $S$.

I am not very experienced with this sort of question - I remember an example, so I did the exact same steps. My final answer is different from the one that the exercise posted, but it may be because there can be multiple basis. Anyway, it's at the bottom.

---

I heard that you should first solve the system

$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & -1 & -3 & 0\\
2 & 0 & 1 & -2 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$-2r_1+r_2$$

$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & -1 & -3 & 0\\
0 & -2 & 3 & 4 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$-\frac{1}{2}r_2$$

$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & -1 & -3 & 0\\
0 & 1 & -3/2 & -2 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$-r_2+r_1$$

$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1/2 & -1 & 0\\
0 & 1 & -3/2 & -2 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$

Now, let

$$x_3 = s\\
x_4 = t$$

The solutions to the system would be

$$x_1 = -\frac{s}{2}+t\\
x_2 = \frac{3s}{2}+2t\\
x_3 = t\\
x_4 = s$$

A basis could then written like

$$B = \{ (x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4) \ | \ s \cdot (-1/2,3/2,0,1) + t \cdot (1,2,1,0)\}$$

$$B = \{ (-1/2,3/2,0,1) , (1,2,1,0) \}$$

It has two dimensions.

---

The answer, from the book, is

$$B = \{ (-1/2,3/2,\color{red}{1,0}) , (1,2,\color{red}{0,1}) \}$$

I got the number of dimensions right, so there's that. However I am not sure if my basis calculation was right (there's a small difference you see). Can you tell if I did it right? This sort of question is still confusing.

Comment: Please read your solution very carefully.  Your method is correct but you have made an extremely careless mistake near the end.

Comment: @David: When I multiplied by $s$, the third term should've been $1$, not the fourth. Ack....... By the way, for this specific method, my basis should always be identical to the solution in the book, right? Or can they differ?

Comment: In general they can differ: a vector space will always have more than one possible basis (except in some very trivial cases).  A good partial check is to make sure that all the vectors in your answer satisfy the original conditions.  If you are asking about using a rigidly specified version of row-reduction then I guess you should get the same answer as the book. . . though you would have to be sure you were doing **exactly** the same reduction as the book.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way:

Let $A=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 2 & 0 \end{bmatrix} $,
$B=\begin{bmatrix} -1 & -3 \\ 1 & -2 \end{bmatrix} $, and note that
$A^{-1} = {1 \over 2} \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 2 & -1 \end{bmatrix} $, and $B$ is
invertible.

Then
the equations can be written as
$A \binom{x_1}{x_2} + B \binom{x_3}{x_4}=0$, or
$\binom{x_1}{x_2} = - A^{-1} B \binom{x_3}{x_4}$.

It follows that the dimension is 2 (since $A^{-1}B$ is invertible), and we can compute a basis by choosing 
$(x_3,x_4) = (1,0)$ and then $(x_3,x_4) = (0, 1)$. Performing the computations
gives
$(-{1 \over 2}, {3 \over 2}, 1 , 0)$,  $(1,2, 0,1)$.